# Port Forwarding multiple Xbox

Tags: port-forwarding, xbox360, playstation

Scenario is;
5 Xbox 360 console. Connected to a router, connected to a modem/router.
Even if it is 3, same scenario.
Wanting to open ports for Xbox Live(I know what ports), when I set up port forwarding I have to set it to an ip address 192.168.0.2(or whatever it is).
How, do I recreate the same ports for other ip addresses. Or how am I to open these ports for other ip addresses, i.e other Xbox 192.168.0.3, 192.168.0.4?
So, in the past MAC address filtering seemed to be the way to go, obviously UpNP as well. Though what I am stating is that without filtering Xbox(x) gets disconnected when Xbox(y) and Xbox(z) are connected. Theory is, Xbox(x,y or z) starts hosting a game or uses a port and disconnects the other. Port Triggering also has not worked. This has been an 8 year battle, and I'm sure I worked it out somewhere along the way, though assistance and advice appreciated. Can I create 4 instances of the Xbox port forwarding table, to open such(or similar) ports to improve stability?
To reduce issues, modem has just been set to a bridge this week.

Comment: Reading up on the subject, xbox forums mentions that not all routers can handle multiple xboxes. It would be important to post your router model before attempting to work on it if that is the case.

Comment: Understandable, though Microsoft are talking about compatability modems and the fix for this(even with those modems/routers) is UPnP or forwarding. The router is a Netgear R6300 to my knowledge.

Comment: Over the 8 years I've tried a few different types of router or modem.

Comment: Logic says, 4 ports to a modem. 4 devices. Shouldn't be a problem. But it is...

Comment: I assume you have tried 2 at a time first right?

Comment: According to what I see that router is supposed to handle it, wired but sometimes not effective wirelessly. So your connections should be fine since I believe you are referring to wired setups.

Comment: the router you have is listed as being able to do this "with Open NAT using "only" UPnP, not port forwarding"

Comment: I am. I've tested it with 1-7 Xbox. 3 is where the issue starts. 2 if one person begins hosting on a matching game. Great connection if the one that gets the ports is host. Dosconnected otherwise.

Comment: Tried that. In the past, MAC address filtering resulted in a brief working period. Not sure what happened.

Comment: You may want to attempt revisiting the UPNP method. Like I said, it is reported to not be able to handle it with port forwarding.

Comment: That's the method I use. It doesn't seem to be stable.

Comment: Is there a way to forward ports to an IP address, then forward the same ports to different ports for another IP address? UPnP shows using a port like 39999 when the Xbox ports are in use giving me a view that I can possibly "remap" or assign port values to triggered ports.

Comment: Are you able to install PFsense? It offers options... https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php/topic,70469.0.html (This one refers to xbox settings)

Comment: Thanks, I will consider it. However I would prefer not to have to use a PC or 3rd party programs as I try to keep the network so minimal, that only the Xbox are generally ran off it. Setting changes are done from my phone or PC if it ever gets turned on.

Comment: In my networking jobs I use dd-wrt (a competitor of pfsense) installed on the routers. It gives upgraded options the routers don't come with. According to what I have read, PFsense appears to like xbox better than dd-wrt.